# Listview async loading and checked state

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I've got a listview with checkboxes. I had performance problems to load all my data on UI thread so now I load the data with an `AsyncTask`. At the end of the `AsyncTask`, I create my adapter with my data and I call setAdapter on the list, so I moved the adapter creation and adapter setting from `onCreate()` to a callback called at the end of the `AsyncTask`. In this way I've got problems with the state of checked boxes. In the original version the state was automatically managed but now no more, why?

Edit: posted adapter

```
private class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView iv;
    }

    private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> itemList;
    private String imageFrom;
    private String textFrom;
    private PackageManager pm;
    private Context c;
    int resLayout;
    int resImage;
    int resText;

    public AppAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data,
            int resource, String image, String text, int resImg, int resTxt) {
        resLayout = resource;
        resImage = resImg;
        resText = resTxt;
        c = context;
        if (data != null)
            itemList = data;
        else
            itemList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        imageFrom = image;
        textFrom = text;
        pm = context.getPackageManager();
    }

    public void loadData(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data) {
        itemList.addAll(data);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(resLayout, parent, false);
            vh.iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(resImage);
            vh.tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(resText);
            v.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            v = convertView;
        }

        if (!itemList.isEmpty()) {
            ApplicationInfo r = (ApplicationInfo) itemList.get(position)
                    .get(imageFrom);
            vh.iv.setImageDrawable(r.loadIcon(pm));
            vh.tv.setText((String) itemList.get(position).get(textFrom));
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use CursorLoader. But I think the problem is in reuse and preparation of ListView's cell. Show me your pseudo code?

Comment: I changed my adapter now and I call a loadData in the callback creating the adapter with null in onCreate and setting the adapter on the list. Now the list remember the checked state but when the activity is created again due to orientation change, it starts from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry! My expectations are largely wrong.
If cells do not have images, the same performance problem occurs?